# django digital ocean git

Tags: django, git, deployment, digital-ocean

I have set up my python, virtualenv, django environment in my digital ocean Ubuntu droplet. I have also set up SSH access to be able to deploy using git. I have set a remote url, so to push I just use "git remote live master". I have used git webhooks to push remotely. Since I used git init --bare for my remote repo, I cannot see the source code, I just see the hooks folders, etc. 
The only issue is after pushing to the remote repository, how do I connect that repository to my django environment so that I can run it, access those source codes, so that I can do "python manage.py runserver"? I am a beginner to webhosting automatic deployment using git and django, I do appreciate your help.

Comment: Seems like, you didn't specified git working directory. Can you show post-receive's contents?